# Relation between midsegment of a trapezoid and midsegment of the diagonals

Tags: geometry

In any given trapezoid, is the midsegment of the entire trapezoid collinear with the midsegment of the diagonals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think so. They should be collinear along the mid segment of the trapezoid.

Comment: Yes, I think the same -- but is this trivial?  Can I say this without having to prove it?

Comment: Maybe simply mention in passing that the midpoint of a diagonal has to appear half way between the vertical distance separating the two parallel sides. Thus any diagonal midpoint will appear somewhere along the mid segment of the trapezoid.